# Nested ng-repeat with model binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

HTML:

```
<div class="panel panel-default" ng-repeat="(section, sectionData) in report">
  <div class="panel-heading">{{sectionData.text}}</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
       <div class="row" ng-repeat="(part, partData) in sectionData.attr">
          <div class="col-md-2">
             <label>{{partData.text}}</label>                            
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="form-group">                        
              <div class="radio-inline" ng-repeat="condition in radioValues">
                <label class="radio-inline">
                   <input type="radio" name="{{section}}-{{part}}" ng-value="{{condition.value}}" ng-model="partData[model]">
                    {{condition.text}}
                 </label>
               </div>                                
             </div>                            
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

JS model:

```
$scope.radioValues = [{
    text: 'Good',
    value: '1'
}, {
    text: 'Average',
    value: '2'
}, {
    text: 'Needs Improvement',
    value: '3'
}];

$scope.report = {
card: {
    text: 'Card',
    attr: {
        front: {
            text: 'Front',
            model: 'detail.report.card.front',
        },
        rear: {
            text: 'Rear',
            model: 'detail.report.card.front.rear'
        },
        assembly: {
            text: 'Assembly',
            model: 'detail.report.card.front.assembly'
        }
    }
} //, and a lot of others like card
};

// Instantiate the model so that values are preselected
for (var section in $scope.report) {
    for (var part in $scope.report[section].attr) {
        initModel($scope.report[section].attr[part]); // basically sets the model values defined in $scope.report to 1
    }
}
```

The $scope.report object is used to create the html and I'm trying to set the value of ng-model in the html to strings defined in the $scope.report. Along with that, I'm also trying to set the default values of each set of radios.

Is the ng-model="partData[model]" part correct? After setting the model values in the controller, the radios aren't preselected when the page loads. The model defined in the $scope.report should bind to the $scope directly. E.g. detail.report.card.front.assembly should actually become $scope.detail.report...

How do I make this work? Is it the right use of angular? Better alternatives?

Comment: I'd tried using value as well. No luck. From what I understood from the docs, that if the model's value == value in the radio, then it is checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this done using a directive with isolated scope.

Basically, I shifted the html to a template called report. I changed the template html a little bit. Here's the changed code:

```
<div class="radio-inline" ng-repeat="condition in radioValues">
  <label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" name="{{section}}-{{part}}" ng-value="{{condition.value}}" ng-model="detail.report[section][part]">
    {{condition.text}}
  </label>
</div>
```

Then created a directive like so:

```
app.module('').directive('rating', function(){
   return {
       scope : {
          report: "=",
          detail: "=",
          radios: "="
       },
       restrict : 'E',
       templateUrl : '../view/rating.html',
       link : function($scope, iElm, iAttrs, controller) {}
   };

});
```

And in the html I simply call:

```
<rating report="report" radios="radios" detail="detail"></rating>
```

So I was able to access the `detail` object in the parent scope by passing it to the template. This allowed me to modify the parent scope's model directly.